# Get File from Directory into NSData

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsdata

I try to get my file in my self created Directory in the Documents Directory into a NSData Object like this:

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",@"/",fileName];

                NSError* errorr = nil;
                NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options: 0 error: &errorr];
                if (fileData == nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to read file, error %@", errorr);
                }
                else
                {

                }
```

But i always get this error:

```
Failed to read file, error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x156be110 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/679253E3-652C-45EE-B589-609E52E4E3B0/Documents/upload/test.xml, NSUnderlyingError=0x156ba7f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"}
```

So if i check if the file is readable:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath: path]  == YES)
                    NSLog (@"File is readable");
                else
                    NSLog (@"File is read only");
```

i get the result that the file is readable, so why do i get the error if i want to parse that file into NSData?!

UPDATE: i created my file like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:fileName];

[xmlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

- (NSString *)dataFilePath: (NSString *) path {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload"];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString *documentsPath = [documentsDirectory
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
return documentsPath;

}
```

UPDATE2: After creating the file, i move it into another Directory with this function:

```
- (void)moveXmlFilesToUploadDirectory
{
@try {
    //Check if FILES_DIR exists
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]     stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILES_DIR];//filesDir
    NSString *uploadDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:UPLOAD_DIR];//filesDir

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory])
    {
        NSString *extension = @"xml";
        NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
        NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
        NSString *filename;
        while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

            if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:documentsDirectory toPath:[uploadDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];

            }
        }
    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
@finally {

}

}
```

Maybe the Problem is after moving the file! Cause if i try to get my file into a NSData before i move it, everything works...

Comment: Can you share your `documentsDirectory` method?

Comment: That´s not a method, it´s a path (NSString)! I create it like this: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload"];

Comment: Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent, not stringByAppendingFormat.

Comment: Same Error if i use: NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", fileName]];

Comment: But you should still use stringByAppendingPathComponent.  You can get bit using the other scheme, and it's more characters to type and less efficient as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you try to copy the whole directory to a destination meant to be a file. The result is that the filepath is a directory path in the end so you can't open it like a file which leads to the permission error message.

You should update your copy code to

```
 while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

            if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename] toPath:[uploadDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];

            }
        }
```

to copy every file individually. That will create than the actual file at the destination path intend of a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The chances are high that you don't have the right permissions for that file. Please check the permissions and add read access for the current user or "everyone". You can set the read permissions for your user by the info dialog (cmd + i) or in the terminal with `chmod u+r test.xml`. Eventually you have to set the owner before with

```
sudo chown yourusername test.xml
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can use the NSFileManager to manipulate file permissions from within your App. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:or just check them with - (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error It would be interesting to know how you created that file?

Comment: result: 
{
    NSFileCreationDate = "2014-01-23 12:36:06 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = mobile;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2014-01-23 12:36:06 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = mobile;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
    NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 2;
    NSFileSize = 102;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 2777322;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 16777219;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
}

Comment: the directory looks fine. What about your the test.xml?

Comment: what are the attributes on your file that you are trying to access? And where does it come from? Are you creating it in App?

Comment: I just posted the Attributes of my file! And i updated my Question where you can see how i created that file! Ye it´s created in App!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45913/discussion-between-chrizstone-and-alexander-ney)

Comment: Sorry I saw the File attributes for a directory https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSFileType_Attribute_Values as you can see it on "NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;" I tought that was your upload directory. The method call [xmlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; is opaque so I can't see what is happening there. But the Fileattributes are wrong then because they are clearly of a Directory instead of a File, maybe thats the problem

Comment: Can you come into chat?!